# How to update vertices geometry of children object after rotate or move parent object

Tags: three.js

I'm confused. Made a group that includes the line. After moving or rotating the parent, the visible line changed, but the vertices remained the same.

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
itemLine = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
item  = new THREE.Group();
item.attach(itemLine);
```

After create  i saw in console:

```
geometry.vertices[0]
Object { x: -540, y: 50, z: 0 }
```

I called

```
item.rotation.z -= deltaAngel;
```

But got

```
geometry.vertices[0]
Object { x: -540, y: 50, z: 0 }
```

Comment: You should look into [scene graph](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex coordinates of `itemLine` are in the space of `item` local.
Rotating `item` doesn't change local coordinates of its children.

Comment: How to convert children coords to world coords?

Comment: Try `geometry.vertices[0].applyMatrix(item.matrixWorld())`. But it changes coords of `geometry.vertices[0]`. If you don't want it, first copy that vertex and apply transform matrix.